# FreeBSD systat doesn't calculate upload speed/total on wlan0

Tags: networking, freebsd, wifi, networkcard

When I call `systat -if` shows that `wlan0` out traffic/peak/total are 0 kb(/s). I'm using `wlan0` for networking, internet down/upload are working. The in traffic/peak/total are OK.

The wifi chip is Atheros 9285, the module is `ath`. System is FreeBSD 10.0.

How can I correct this?

If you need some information, command output, etc. I'll share.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bug is currently being investigated by the developers.

It seems the outbound traffic may be being mis-accounted and assigned to the physical device (`iwn0` or `ath0`, etc) instead of `wlan0`

try these two commands to confirm:

`netstat -I wlan0 -i 1` (shows only incoming traffic)

`netstat -I ath0 -i 1` (shows only outgoing traffic)

See this thread: http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-current/2014-June/050565.html

Specifically: http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-current/2014-June/050631.html